# XML, array on PHP special characters issue

Tags: php, xml

Hi im doing a RSS feed from an XML file, its ok . but the special latin characters are not echoing properly, the rest of the page is doing it.. i think i neet to convert the array to utf8 some how.

This is working for the page, if i change this to UTF i got ? insteaad of the character itself

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

Here is my code (part of it)

```
   $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->loadXML( curl_load('http://www.laesquinadelamoda.com/feed/') );

    //Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode($rss);



    $feed = array();




    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array (
```

How can i fix the array to dispay UTF8 characters correctly

Comment: Try just `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Also, you should be able to open the feed with `$rss->load('http://www.laesquinadelamoda.com/feed/')`

Comment: thanks that works but the rest of the page , is not working cause special charecters in there are displayed like "� � �" when i set just  to <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: You'll need to show the code where you output the data that is displaying incorrectly. Your meta tag should be near the top of your `<head>` block as well, before anything else incorrectly sets the encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the HTTP response Content-Type header to the UTF-8 encoding because that is the encoding you use when you output from SimpleXMLElement properties:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
#################################################

$url = 'http://www.laesquinadelamoda.com/feed/';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item)
{        
     echo $item->title, "<br>\n";
}
```

Output :

```
¿Qué es un serum antimanchas?
Cosmética masculina en nuestras perfumerías
Prendas para renovar el armario masculino
Un poco de street style masculino
Cálzate unas zapatillas
Looks con prendas de Sfera
Looks con prendas de Springfield y Stradivarius
Viste tus gadgets con las mejores galas
Ropa interior moldeadora
Cómo elegir una barra de labios roja
```